# For which primes p does the series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (\frac{10}{11})^i$ converge p-adically

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

For which primes p does the series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (\frac{10}{11})^i$ converge p-adically and, when it does, to what limit?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $p$-adic analysis is a doll when infinite series is involved since a series converges iff its general term's sequence converges to zero, so the question is:

$$\left(\frac{10}{11}\right)^n\stackrel ?{\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0}\;\;p-\text{adically}$$

Comment: that's great thanks, but I'm having difficulty finding $ord_{p}\left(\frac{10}{11}\right)^n$ and then using this to find limit of $p^{-ord_{p}\left(\frac{10}{11}\right)^n}$ @Thomas Andrews

Comment: I'm also thinking: unless p=2,5,11 then this series will not converge. Because $\frac{10}{11}^n$ will be st its $ord_p=0$ so is the answer p=2,5,11? and also can order of p be negative? @DonAntonio

Comment: I think answer is 2 0r 5 because it diverges for p=11

Comment: and the limit now? How do I find that

Comment: Well, we have $\,\left(\frac{10}{11}\right)^n=\frac{2^n5^n}{11^n}\,$ , so what primes *actually* divide this expression? For example, $$ord_{11}\left(\frac{10}{11}\right)^n=11^n\ldots$$

Comment: And BTW: your insights about $\,2,5,11\,$ are completely on the right track. Try now to formalize.

Comment: the only primes that divide that expression are 2, 5 and 11, but the sequence (10/11)^n diverges for p=11 and conv. for other 2 values. It seems that I need to expand this series, guess the padic limit and then test to see if that's correct?